# Como puedo obtener este resultado de R en sql studio?

Tags: sql-server, r

Tengo este problema al momento de ejecutar la función me da como resultado el select que esto requiriendo en el `@input_data_1` pero quisiera obtener en si el resultado de la siguiente imagen [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx7oy.jpg)

El código que estoy utilizando es diseñado en r pero lo estoy ejecutando en sql por EXEC `sp_execute_external_script` este es el código

```sql
EXEC sp_execute_external_script  @language =N'R',
    @script=N'
    library("dplyr");
    data<-data.frame(data%>%
      mutate(sf=data$DSBE_FL_SALDO_INICIAL-data$DSBE_FL_RETIROS+data$DSBE_FL_DEPOSITOS)%>% 
      mutate(cuentas=ifelse(data$DSBE_A1_CUENTA_CONTABLE==210305,1,0)+ifelse(data$DSBE_A1_CUENTA_CONTABLE==210310,1,0))%>% 
      mutate(bce=ifelse(data$DSBE_A2_ID_CLIENTE==1760002600001,0,1)) 
      data<-data%>%
      mutate(val=ifelse(data$cuentas*data$bce==1,1,0))%>%
      filter(val==1)
      datac<-  data %>% 
      group_by(DSBE_A6_NOMBRE_CLIENTE) %>% 
      summarize(sum_sf=sum(sf))
      datac<-datac%>%
      mutate(tot=sum(sum_sf))%>%
      mutate(w=sum_sf/tot)%>%
      mutate(w_2=w^2)%>%
      arrange(desc(sum_sf))
      hhi<-sum(datac$w_2)
      rq<-max(datac$tot)*0.5
      (mensaje<-requerimeinto_liquidez<-ifelse(hhi>0.18,"50% mayores depositantes","Mayor valor entre Volatilidad ABS y 50% mayores dep"))
      (requerimeinto_liquidez<-ifelse(hhi>0.18,rq,0)))
    ',
    @input_data_1 =N'SELECT * from  DEPOSITANTES_SBE_CARGA WHERE DSBE_DT_FECHA_PIVOT = ''2021-08-31''',@input_data_1_name = N'data',
    --WITH RESULT SETS (([campo_1] varchar(60)))
     @output_data_1_name = N'data';
GO
```

Comment: Bienvenido Jorge Meza a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Tienes un script en R que dicho sea de paso, no tiene nada del otro mundo y podrías transformar el código a SQL básico, lo ejecutas con sp_execute_external_script, luego ¿que pasa? ¿no funciona? ¿te da algún tipo de error?

Comment: Hola Patricio, muchas gracias por tu respuesta ya logre solucionar el error, el error era que no podía ejecutar el script porque necesitaba instalar la librería de dplyr, tuve que cambiar mi versión de sql por la del 2017 para que pueda instalar la librería y ejecutar el script. Voy a dejar la respuesta solucionada, espero que alguien le sirva saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver esta duda lo primero que realice fue cambiar de versión la sql server 2017 instalando el paquete de machine learning que incluye los paquete de R y python, aquí dejo e link para que instalen sql server: [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/instalacion-paso-a-paso-del-sql-server-2017/)

una vez instalado el sql 2017, procedí a instalar la librería necesaria para que se pueda ejecutar el script yo necesitaba instalar en este caso la librería (dplyr) para instalar una librería de R para que sirva en sql le dejo el enlace que tome de guía: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/package-management/install-r-packages-standard-tools?view=sql-server-2017.
unas vez instalada la librería me dirigí a mi script de sql y lo ejecute de la siguiente manera adjunto el código:

```html
EXEC sp_execute_external_script  @language =N'R',
@script=N'
library(dplyr);
data<-data.frame(
  data%>%
  mutate(sf=data$DSBE_FL_SALDO_INICIAL-data$DSBE_FL_RETIROS+data$DSBE_FL_DEPOSITOS)  
 #mutate(cuentas=ifelse(data$DSBE_A1_CUENTA_CONTABLE==210305,1,0)+ifelse(data$DSBE_A1_CUENTA_CONTABLE==210310,1,0))%>% 
 #mutate(bce=ifelse(data$DSBE_A2_ID_CLIENTE==1760002600001,0,1))
  )
#data<-data.frame(
#   data<-data%>%
#  mutate(val=ifelse(data$cuentas*data$bce==1,1,0))%>%
#  filter(val==1)
#)
data<-data.frame(
    datac<-  data %>% 
  group_by(DSBE_A6_NOMBRE_CLIENTE) %>% 
  summarize(sum_sf=sum(sf))
)
data<- data.frame(
   datac<-datac%>%
  mutate(tot=sum(sum_sf))%>%
  mutate(w=sum_sf/tot)%>%
  mutate(w_2=w^2)%>%
  arrange(desc(sum_sf))
) 
data<- data.frame(
    hhi<-sum(datac$w_2)
)
data<- data.frame(
    rq<-max(datac$tot)*0.5
)
data<- data.frame(
    mensaje<-requerimeinto_liquidez<-ifelse(hhi>0.18,"50% mayores depositantes","Mayor valor entre Volatilidad ABS y 50% mayores dep")
)
data<- data.frame(
    requerimeinto_liquidez<-ifelse(hhi>0.18,rq,0)
)
',
@input_data_1 =N'SELECT * from  DEPOSITANTES_SBE_CARGA WHERE DSBE_DT_FECHA_PIVOT = ''2021-08-31''AND DSBE_A1_CUENTA_CONTABLE IN (''210305'',''210310'') AND DSBE_A2_ID_CLIENTE <>''1760002600001''',
@input_data_1_name = N'data',
@output_data_1_name = N'data'
WITH RESULT SETS (([campo_1] float));
GO
```

el código tiene cierto cambios para que funcione pero espero que alguien le pueda servir de guía saludos.